# How to select all the vertexes with border select?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

Hi guys I'm new to Blender, and have this question about selecting vertexes.

I tried to select all vertexes within a rectangle region by drawing the rectangle with mouse after pressing <kbd>B</kbd> in Top View, but I actually ended up with only selecting the vertexes that are closer to me.

Here are my steps:

1. After pressing <kbd>B</kbd> I selected multiple vertexes with drawing a rectangle:
   [image]
2. I deleted them with <kbd>X</kbd>, but I see some in that region actually still exist:
   [image]
3. You can see I actually only selected the upper 2 which were closer to me:
   [image]

So is there a way to really do this? I'm using Blender 2.71, but I saw Jonathan could do it in this video (but he must be using an older version): [CGCookie tutorial: Modeling a Shipping Container](http://cgcookie.com/archive/modeling-a-shipping-container/)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5004/599

Comment: If you were in wireframe view like your screenshots suggest, this should have worked..

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks it worked! I just turned Wireframe mode on in the Cube panel at the right hand side but didn't notice it sometimes changes back to Texture.

Comment: The per-object draw settings shouldn't affect the selection, only the global viewport shading settings in 3D view > header (next to the mode selection drop down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the regular behaviour of Blender. By default "Limit selection to visible (clipped with depth buffer)" is enabled.

When you disable the button I marked in the screenshot, select the vertices again, all four vertices will be selected.

[image: limit_selection_to_visible]

Comment: Though in wireframe view, blender *always* selects all vertices, regardless of that setting.. As a matter of fact, it's not even available in wireframe view.