# How to Select ALL objects in a scene Since Face parts are not selected?

Tags: modeling

See this is why i actually despise using Blender.Not only is it not noobie friendly but you can't undo mistakes and in my case one mistake and it's over. I have to literally start all over. What i'm doing: I'm importing a scene,Yes,a whole scene from a video game for the PSP.Yes i have and use a device that can do this to any game of my choosing.The problem: I am trying to select only the characters however they're apparently a bit too detailed for blender. When i move them (Position them for export after i'm done selecting manually) bits and pieces get left behind. Very vital pieces(Mainly eyeballs,tongues and on some occasions,eyebrows.) are not getting moved.Why? I couldn't select it. I'm sick of it. This is the 8th time. I'm getting very pissed with it. I want these girls extracted but blender just one select the face parts.

Additional info thats needed just in case

Game:Photo Kano
System:PSP
Emulator:Jap-Emulator

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the scene's [outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html)?

Comment: It looks like you have *Limit Selection To Visible* enabled, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/how-to-select-all-the-vertexes-with-border-select. Also you can switch to Wireframe shading mode (`Z`) to select with selection tools or press `Ctrl`+`L` once any vertex of mesh selected to select all connected vertices of mesh.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>A</kbd> selects all objects on the stage.
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right mouse button</kbd> to select multiple object one after the other.
Try not to be in render mode when selecting objects.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo. You can undo as many times as your preferences allow.