# Drag select with mouse

Tags: selection-tools

Is it possible to select the objects by dragging left mouse button like in other CAD or 3D softwares. If i change the keyboard shortcuts to Maya in the settings I could do that. But I dont know which key is mapped to that. This could be done with box select but i want to achieve something by clicking on blank screen and dragging the mouse.

[image: This was done using dragging left mouse button with Maya keyboard shortcuts as default]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5004/599

Answer (score 13):

I believe that you are looking for <kbd>B</kbd>. <kbd>B</kbd> allows for exactly what you describe -- Box Select. Upon its being pressed, the cursor turns into a crosshair and awaits your <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> dragging. Note that you can additionally use <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to Box Deselect.

It works as an additive or subtractitive tool, only selecting more or less, never affecting ones already selected or deselected. It works in every editor that you can select something (not just the *3D Viewport* but the *UV Image Editor*, *Graph Editor*, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for your answers. I am aware of Box select <kbd>B</kbd> but I figured out the shortcut it is mapped to.

So this is how I did it I went to 
*File > User Preferences > Input > 3D view > 3D view Global* and  the settings of

`view3d.select_border` to <kbd>Tweak</kbd> + <kbd>select</kbd> + <kbd>any</kbd> then I could select the way wanted it to be.

Its really useful at time while working with a lot of meshes.

Comment: I have set up a similar hotkey. To expand it further, I have also create ctr+drag to deselect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set this yourself in the user preferences.

*Navigate to File > User Preferences > Input > 3D view > 3D view Global* 
Navigate to the end of the list and add a new operator. The operator you are looking for is `view3d.select_border`

Then change the event type to *Tweak, Select, Any*

Add as many as you like for modifier keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Have in mind that you may have to manually clear any other operators using the *mouse tweak* event so there are no conflicts which may cause the new hotkey to fail. Use the search function at the top for *Key Binding* to find conflicts